# How to run Spark 3.0.0 on HDP (Horthonworks)?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, hdp

Is there a way to run a Spark 3.0 on HDP3 (Horthonworks)?
I'm aware that there is always a standalone option, but I would like to configure YARN as a scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDP 7.1.3 onwards, you can use **Spark3**.

https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.3/cds-3/topics/spark-spark-3-overview.html

**Installation Steps:**

https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.3/cds-3/topics/spark-install-spark-3-parcel.html